# Simple Injector support for Xamarin Forms 4.0

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, simple-injector

We are planning to use [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) with the Xamarin Forms 4.0 and is struggling to find any documentation around this. The issue is when we try to inject the ViewModel to a Page (using constructor injection) as below;

```
 public partial class FinderPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly IFinderViewModel _viewModel;

    public FinderPage(IFinderViewModel finderViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = finderViewModel;            
    }
```

However, the system returns the following error response;

> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type BuzzBingo.BingoBuddy.Views.ClubFinderPage

Please note that we are using SimpleInjector as the IoC container.

```
container.Register<IClubFinderViewModel, ClubFinderViewModel>();
```

Comment: Have you tried following this guide?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection. For your question to be suitable for Stack Overflow, it needs to be much more concrete. After reading that guide, try making your question more specific, and add more details on what part you are struggling with.

Comment: Edited with more detail

Comment: You need to hook Simple Injector to Xamarin's `ServiceLocator` as explained here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/10/03/dependency-injection-xamarin/